# polymer data-bind iron ajax and access fetched JSON in console

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, polymer

### **I am able to fetch json data using iron-ajax and bind to the DOM. But unable to access ajaxResponse in script.**

```
<template id="t" is="dom-bind">
        <iron-ajax 
        auto
        id="dataAjax" 
        url="data.json"
        last-response={{ajaxResponse}}></iron-ajax>

        <p>Data from ajax: <span>{{ajaxResponse.id}}</span> <span>{{ajaxResponse.val}}</span> </p>


</template>
```

---

**How to access ajaxResponse in the script and view json data ?**

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code. You nee to wrap `{{ajaxResponse}}` in parentheses.

```
<template id="t" is="dom-bind">
        <iron-ajax 
        auto
        id="dataAjax" 
        url="data.json"
--      last-response={{ajaxResponse}}></iron-ajax>
++      last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
        <p>Data from ajax: <span>{{ajaxResponse.id}}</span> <span>{{ajaxResponse.val}}</span> </p>
</template>
```

Here's a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/liroyoy/edit?html,output) of a basic working `iron-ajax` demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like that: `document.getElementById('dataAjax').lastResponse`
But you have to make sure you don't have error and the request completed.

You can also make use of `handle-as="json"`